# Jackson JsonNode and Java Streams to return Optional Empty

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-stream, option-type

So I have a json input, something like this:

```
{
    "a":"something",
    "b":"something2"
}
```

This input can come in 2 other forms:

```
{
    "a":"something",
    "b":""
}
```

And

```
{
    "a":"something"
}
```

I have a input class like this that I store it in:

```
public class Foo {
    private String a;
    private Optional<String> b;
}
```

In the latter 2 cases I want to store b as Optional.empty(). I have figured out how to do that in the 3rd case with this line of code:

```
Optional.ofNullable(inputNode.get("b")).map(node -> node.asText())
```

This works well for the 3rd case. It returns Optional.empty. But not so much for the 2nd case because `b` ends up just being an empty string. I tried to use `.reduce` before and after the `.map` but for some reason it won't let me use that anywhere.

And idea how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter the Optional to check that the value is not the empty String:

```
Optional<String> b = Optional.ofNullable(inputNode.get("b"))
        .map(JsonNode::asText)
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 0):

This code also helps:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(jsonNode.findValue("XYZ")).map(JsonNode::asText).orElse(null);
```